# Max no. of elements that can be stored in the std::vector<int>

Tags: c++

As we can store 10^7 elements in array,if we are required to store the elements >= 10^9 then how can we do that?

Comment: Combine two or more vectors?

Comment: depends on your memory

Comment: Depends on the runtime. You probably can. But rather than asking a question, why don't you share the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/max_size

Comment: Do you _really_ need that many elements?? That's 1GB even if each element only takes _one_ byte.

Comment: When you write "store the elements >= 10^9", I get a feeling that you're perhaps mixing up the number of elements in the vector and the value of the elements.

Comment: *if we are required to store the elements >= 10^9*  -- Tell us why it is required to store this many elements.  The question as it stands looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Max no. of elements that can be stored in the std::vector

Depends on the limitations of the system that runs the program. On a 64 bit system, the maximum is most likely limited by the amount of physical memory your system has available.

> if we are required to store the elements >= 10^9 then how can we do that?

Then call `vec.resize(1'000'000'000)`. That's less than 4 gigabytes of memory (on typical systems).

Comment: Presumably the limit would be physical memory _plus swap_.

Comment: _"That's less than 4 gigabytes of memory (on typical systems)"_ Depends what the element type is.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Element type of `std::vector<int>` is `int`.

Comment: @MSalters In theory, and probably depending on how the memory is used. Swap can be too slow to be in active use in practice.

Comment: @eerorika Haha I didn't see the title :D